# Running a url scipt inside php (that contains ajax)

Tags: php, ajax, curl, cron

I have a site that sends urls via email to my client, once they receive them they click the link, it loads in a browser and completes some Ajax that calls a PHP script. There are several AJAX functions being called in this script.

They have requested that this process be automated so they dont have to click the link and wait approximately 15 minutes each time for all the Ajax to be complete.

Ideally, without recoding the functionality and continuing to use the exact same Ajax I would love to automate this process. So I would like to run a cron that loads a script that calls these URLS instead.

Is this possible?

I have tried several things, but nothing is happening when I load the script. When I mean nothing I mean neither errors, nor the functionality of the script. (I have error reporting turned on).

E.g.

cUrl

```
init_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/myscript.php?varialbe=sample_get_content");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

exec

```
exec('http://example.com/myscript.php');
```

simply opening the script...

```
$contents = file_get_contents('http://example.com/myscript.php?varialbe=sample_get_content');
```

I know that another option is to rebuild the functionality so that Im not using AJAX, but I would prefer not do that as it will take time.

EDIT: The actual script URL itself being called changes due to change in GET variables, so I cannot run it directly via cron (or can I?)

Comment: Does script reading URL parameters like $_REQUEST of $_GET?

Comment: Why don't you simply run myscript.php as a CGI - ie call it directly via cron. Just add #!/path/to/phpcgibin -q as the first line of the script

Comment: @KevInSol, actually I'll update my question to clarify that, the reason is that the url of the script is different every time (different GET variables), (unless its possible to still do it somehow?)

Comment: OK, and actually I was going to add, if myscript.php makes ajax calls, it needs to be run by a browser as it's the browser that makes tha ajax cal, maybe that is your issue?

Comment: @RubenKazumov, Im not sure I understand your question, but the script does use parameters like $_GET yes

Comment: @KevInSol, ah ok, I see that makes sense, so its quite likely impossible what Im trying to do

Comment: Based on your edit. You can have an intermediary php script that you call via cron. That script can set up the GET variable and anything else needed. Then it will call the other script.

Comment: I recommend copy and rewrite the script as a function with the single argument and use `include` directive.

Comment: Yes - I think you really should do all this at the server - since you "have a site that sends urls " (assume you wrote that site) why not cut out that step and process that data there?

Comment: Yes its looking like thats the only solution. Its my site alright,I guess the only reason I didnt want to do it is I had spent quite alot of time building the script to work with the browser, and also it designed to call the ajax requests in stages so I will have to redo that. Thanks for the help

Comment: Web server and AJAX is a totally different things. You can not create XMLHttpRequest object from PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested approach.

In script that sends link, instead of sending a link with unique GET data, have it do this:

```
exec("./myscript.php $param_1 $param_2");
```

In myscript.php replace:

```
$param_1 = $_GET['param_1'];
$param_2 = $_GET['param_2'];
```

With

```
$param_1 = $argv[1];
$param_2 = $argv[2];
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Also add

```
#!/path/to/phpcgibin -q
```

to myscript.php before the `<?` and make sure to upload as ascii

Comment: Thanks , but what about the issue with the ajax with no browser?

Comment: I think you would have to re-work thinks to dispense with the ajax, which is a good thing, as at the least, you are removing calls across the network